# Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebView

Tags: react-native

I have used two social login and both are refers the react-native-webview dependency.

installed versions:
react-native-linkedin(it uses react-native-webview 7.0.5),
react-native-instagram-login (it uses react-native-webview 7.5.1),
react-native-webview ^7.5.1

Can you please tell me how to resolve this issue

screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETW5J.png

Answer (score 0):

facing same issue with same library . It is cause of different versions of webview which these library are using and as much as i know we can update those npm module directly so we can solve this issue temporary by following these steps

- Create file InstaWebView.js(name can be any)
- Copy code from
  https://github.com/hungdev/react-native-instagram-login/blob/master/Instagram.js
- Paste in InstaWebView.js and use as normal

I know it is hack but for now we can do this
Note :- For this hack , you need to install webview module so you may install webview module of same version as linkedin has so there will be no issue